# How to redo a git restore? All my saved files in the directory are gone

Tags: git

I am new to git. I have been using jupyter to write my code. I didn't commit any of my changes, but I saved the jupyter notebook in the directory. I accidentally ran a
`$ git restore .` on a branch and all my changes are gone now. I tried to search jupyter cache and saved files, but apparently that one line of code restored/reset my whole directory and none of jupyter saved changes or my git branch were there anymore.

Is there a way to find my lost work? If I didn't commit any of my changes, will git still have a copy of my work anywhere? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you mess up *before* you've made any commits, it's not recoverable. Git can only help you with what it's stored.

Comment: The base answer is unfortunately : if it never reached git before, git hasn't stored any copy of those files. By any chance : even without committing, have you ever run `git add` on your files ?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I didn't run `git add` either... but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is no. If you have not made any commits then you cannot revert back to an older repository state.